# window.open in google chart select function, not firing

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function (e) {
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        var url = "task_log.aspx?id=" + selection[0].row;
        window.open(url);
    });
```

I'm trying to use window.open within a google chart event listener but it's no t firing..any ideas?

The url is correct, when alerted out it does contain correct paramaters.

Thanks,

Comment: try like this window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');

Comment: hmmm, doesn't seem to have worked. Maybe something within google charts that prevents this.

Comment: actually that did work @Talha..window.open(url,'_self'); to open in same page. Popups were d'oh!